# Changing ID to something more friendly

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

When creating a record the URL generated to view that record ends with its id

```
/record/21
```

I would like to be able to change that to something easier to read, such as my name and reference attributes from the model. I have looked at friendly_id but has trouble implementing a custom method to generate the URL

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name_and_ref

  def name_and_ref
   "#{name}-#{reference}"
  end
end
```

I ended up getting an error

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column animals.name_and_ref does not exist LINE 1: SELECT "animals".* FROM "animals" WHERE "animals"."name_an... ^ : SELECT "animals".* FROM "animals" WHERE "animals"."name_and_ref" = 'Clawd-A123456' ORDER BY "animals"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

def show
  @animal = Animal.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

I then come across the to_param method which Rails has available, in my model I have

```
def to_param
  "#{self.id}-#{self.name}"
end
```

which will generate a URL for me of

```
/19-clawd
```

This works, but when I do the following it throws an error

```
def to_param
  "#{self.name}-#{self.reference}"
end
```

My question though is how can I generate the URL to be name and reference without it throwing

```
Couldn't find Animal with 'id'=Clawd-A123456
```

Comment: you're rewriting RESTful design, I would highly advise you to not go down this road...

Comment: so you would advise to stick with the /id urls ?

Comment: Yes, take a look at [this](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html)

Comment: see the answers below.  Bu do you expect users to type in the URL by hand? or is your reason for doing it to look pretty?  If the latter. Just make sure to include the id as the first part of to_param and they will be prettier, and still work without having to rewrite your finds

Comment: its all for SEO and to look prettier(readable).

Comment: then `"#{self.id}-#{self.name}-#{self.reference}"` would be the path of least resistance in my mind

Comment: would removing the id in that path be to much effort and cause too many problems? or should i just deal with the fact that the id stays, as it is a quicker way of finding the record and i wont have to re index my model then will i ? performance will play a part further down the line

Comment: removing the ID, the you need to do all you finds by the name as @pete says below. and yes would need re-index your db (but if you are already searching by name and name is unique, it should probably  already be indexed).  by default rails just .to_i the :id, and searches for it as the primary key. If you change that, then you need to adjust your indexes as required (shouldn't be an slower,assuming you build them correctly for your db)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use your own "friendly id" then you'll need to adjust the find statement in your controller to something like

```
id = params[:id].split(/-/, 2).first
@animal = Animal.find(id)
```

Similarly, for the name/reference combination

```
name, reference = params[:id].split(/-/, 2)
@animal = Animal.find_by(name: name, reference: reference)
```

The second choice is a little more difficult because you'll have to do some work in the model to guarantee that the name/reference pair is unique.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, is to go with friendly_id and simply add the missing database column. Keep in mind that you will need to ensure this new column is unique for every record. It basically acts as primary key.